# In Azure, how to prevent a user create a Network Interface Card but not modify it?

Tags: networking, azure, nic, rbac, azure-policies

I want to give a **specific RBAC** to a user so that **he can create a NIC but not to modify**. As a matter of fact, what it is aimed is that he shouldn't have permission to change the dynamic ip to static ip and change the ip address of the NIC.

I have checked the [RBACs of NIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmRXu.png), but it seems that if he has **`Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write`** permission **, he can create a network interface or update an existing network interface**. So this Rbac is not as detailed as i want.
[image]
I have also tried to give all permissions but not `Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read`. In that case, the NIC can be created but i can neither see the ip of the nic nor ssh/rdp to the VM. So it is not a solution for me.

I have checked the built-in Azure Policies, but there isn't nothing good for my needs.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for someone to have permissions to create a resource but not edit it, as it is all contained under the write permission.

Your best bet would be to use Azure Policy to define a policy that doesn't allow static IP addresses.

Comment: do you have some tips to create a policy to deny static IP addresses?

Comment: i see that to deny public ip, this condition is set:           "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipconfigurations[*].publicIpAddress.id",
              "notLike": "*"
            } . Where can i find the properties of ipconfigurations?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networkinterfaces?tabs=json